# How to disable the Windows pop-up message "You need to format the disk..." without removing drive letter

Tags: windows-7, usb

I making a test program for my USB sticks but every time I plug in one of the USB's sticks Windows shows me the pop-up window "You need to format the disk...".
Is it possible to let Windows not show this message without removing the drive letter (this is the solution I found but is not a solution for me because my drive needs to have a drive letter).
When I replug the USB, Windows needs to mount my USB again, but just not show the message.

Thanks,

Comment: The question is not the same because when I replug the USB, Windows needs to mount my USB again, but just not show the message.

Comment: Why does it need the assigned drive letter?

Comment: I use this in my program to write files to the USB stick and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for testing purposes on your machine you could write yourself a quick [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) script that automatically closes the popup the second it appears.

```
While 1
   WinClose("Microsoft Windows", "You need to format the disk in drive")
   Sleep (1000)
Wend
```

Can't reproduce the popup here but I think this should work.

Comment: This is probably a good solution.
Any idee how I can enable the WinClose() function in C#?

Comment: If I understood you correctly you're trying to implement the same functionality that AutoIt provides into your own application? If so, this might be a start: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248444/how-to-close-the-window-by-its-name. Although I would stick to AutoIt for testing as it's way easier :)

Comment: Exactly, but I do not really have an idea how at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks adiuva, it works wit Autolt. 
But is there a possibility to also let the application check if "You need to format the disk I: before you can use it." is in the pop-up and only then close the pop-up?
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQFaG.png)
[Pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp8o0.png)